# can't get recursive function to work

Tags: php, function, recursion, menu, nav

I'm trying to build a nav menu that populates the first few levels of the nav from a database and then loops around to rerun part of the code to find any other sub levels.

The code below works perfectly for populating the first few levels but breaks if I try to place everything between the ---------- lines into a function and then call that function within itself. I can't work out what I'm doing wrong and would really appreciate some fresh eyes to have a look and tell me if I've made a silly mistake or if the way I'm doing it just can't work. If it can't work the way I'm doing it is there a tweak I can make to make it work?

Thanks.

p.s. first code block = current working code plus --------- lines, second code block is all code including the way i'm trying to build and call the loopMenu function. Third block is how I'm calling the buildMenu6 function.

So this works as intended:

```
<?php
function buildMenu6 ($allpages, $childpageids, $childpages, $subchildpages) {
    foreach ($childpageids as $childid){
        $c[] = $childid['id'];
    };
    echo "<ul>\n";  
    foreach ($allpages as $pages){
        $a = $pages['parentid'];
        $b = $pages['id'];
        if (!in_array($b, $c)){
            echo "<li><a href=" . $pages['url'] . ">" . $pages['linklabel'] . "</a>";
            //------------------------------------------------------------------    
            echo"<ul>\n";
            foreach ($childpages as $childparent) {
                $d = $childparent['parentid'];
                $e = $childparent['id'];
                if (($d == $b) or ($d == $g)) {
                    echo "<li><a href=" . $childparent['url'] . ">" . $childparent['linklabel'] . "</a>";
                    echo "<ul>\n";
                    foreach ($subchildpages as $subchild){
                        $g = $subchild['id'];
                        $f = $subchild['parentid'];
                        if ($f == $e){
                            echo "<li><a href=" . $subchild['url'] . ">" . $subchild['linklabel'] . "</a>";
                            echo "<li/>";
                        };
                    };
                    echo"</ul>\n";
                    echo "</li>";
                };
            };
            echo "</ul>\n";
            //---------------------------------------------------------         
            echo "</li>";
        };
    };
    echo "</ul>\n";
}; ?>
```

This doesn't work as intended: (ps //START LOOPMENU FUNCTION and other // are not in original code, ive just added them for ease of identification)

```
<?php
function buildMenu6 ($allpages, $childpageids, $childpages, $subchildpages) {
    foreach ($childpageids as $childid){
        $c[] = $childid['id'];
    };

    echo "<ul>\n";  
    foreach ($allpages as $pages){
        $a = $pages['parentid'];
        $b = $pages['id'];

        if (!in_array($b, $c)){
            echo "<li><a href=" . $pages['url'] . ">" . $pages['linklabel'] . "</a>";
            function loopMenu($childpages, $subchildpages){ //START LOOPMENU FUNCTION
                echo"<ul>\n";
                foreach ($childpages as $childparent) {
                    $d = $childparent['parentid'];
                    $e = $childparent['id'];
                    if (($d == $b) or ($d == $g)) {
                        echo "<li><a href=" . $childparent['url'] . ">" . $childparent['linklabel'] . "</a>";
                        echo "<ul>\n";
                        foreach ($subchildpages as $subchild){
                            $g = $subchild['id'];
                            $f = $subchild['parentid'];
                            if ($f == $e){
                                echo "<li><a href=" . $subchild['url'] . ">" . $subchild['linklabel'] . "</a>";
                                loopMenu($childparent, $subchild); // CALL FUNCTION LOOPMENU
                                echo "<li/>";
                            };
                        };

                        echo"</ul>\n";
                        echo "</li>";

                    };
                };
                echo "</ul>\n";

            };          //END LOOPMENU FUNCTION 

            loopMenu($childpages, $subchildpages); //CALL FUNCTION LOOPMENU

            echo "</li>";
        };

    };
    echo "</ul>\n";
}; ?>
```

Finally I call buildMenu6 like so:

```
<?php buildMenu6($pageids, $childPageIds, $childPageArray, $childPageArray); ?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I've been going in circles with this for days now!

Comment: well, first of all you should remove the function definition from your loop. You can't re-re-re-re-redefine the same function over and over. It'll just produce a huge error. Same thing for defining a function inside another function: not possible either. Move the definition of the loopMenu out to i.e. the top of the page.

Comment: thank you I thought this would probably be a suggestion but I wasn't sure. I have however done as you say previously and moved loopMenu outside of buildMenu6 and I still couldn't get it to work? Is there anything else going wrong here? Many thanks

Comment: @Tularis could you clarify whether I have understood what you mean by 'remove the function definition from your loop' please? I'm just thinking that I have understood it to mean remove loopMenu from buildMenu6 but if there's anything else I need to do then I'm not clear what it would be. thanks again